# Empty Parameter showing Error 404 .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

https://northbengaltourism.com/hotel-details/sikkim/lachung/NBTH0329/ is working properly by using:

`RewriteRule ^hotel-details/?(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*)/$ hotel-details.php?hotdest=$1&hotcity=$2&hotelid=$3`

in htaccess. But when the two middle parameters are missing, the page shows:

`Error 404 (Not Found). https://northbengaltourism.com/hotel-details///NBTH0329/`

I tried `([^/]*)` in place of `(.*)` but no luck. Please help me to solve this.